# How to animate a slided list (up / down) in Angular/Twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

Help your internet buddy out, will ya! :)

I'm trying to make a smooth sliding up&down list in angular but I just can't figure it out. I'm not too experience with CSS and I'm still learning but I gave it my best shot: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmyeXb

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">

  <!-- button up -->
  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="up()">up</button>

  <div style="width: 25%;margin-left: 37%" class="bg-info p-3 container">
    <ul class="list-group">

      <!-- list item to be animated -->
      <li class="list-group-item m-1" ng-class="slide=='up' ? 'slide-up':'slide-down '" ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- button down -->
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="down()">down</button>  

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-up.ng-enter {
    animation: slideInDown 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slideInDown 1s;
}


.slide-up.ng-leave {
    animation: slideOutDown 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slideOutDown 1s;

}

.slide-down.ng-enter {
    animation: slideInUp 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slideInUp 1s;
}

.slide-down.ng-leave {
    animation: slideOutUp 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slideOutUp 1s;

}
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];



  $scope.up = function() {
    $scope.slide='up';
      $scope.items.splice($scope.items.length-1, 1);
      $scope.items.unshift($scope.items[0]-1);
  }

    $scope.down = function() {
      $scope.slide='down';
      $scope.items.splice(0, 1);
      $scope.items.push($scope.items[$scope.items.length-1]+1);
  }
});
```

The list item that's getting removed is still taking up space until animation is done, that doesn't look too good. Any advices on how I should approach this? Is there any better way for animating list items in angular?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly understand you. If you need to prevent animation for removing item do following:

CSS

```
.slide-up.ng-leave {
    animation: slideOutDown 0s;
    -webkit-animation: slideOutDown 0s;
}

.slide-down.ng-leave {
   animation: slideOutUp 0s;
  -webkit-animation: slideOutUp 0s;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also I think I found what you are looking

You can make slides with **ng-leave** absolute positioned, so the will not take space.

```
.slide-up.ng-leave {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   animation: slideOutDown 1s;
   -webkit-animation: slideOutDown 1s; 
 }


.slide-down.ng-leave {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: slideOutUp 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slideOutUp 1s;
 }
```

And do not forget about this

```
 ul {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kmzagw)